# Google speech-to-text ListRecognizers

Tags: google-cloud-speech

What kind of output should I expect from the Google v2 speech-to-text API for the [list_recognizers](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/speech/latest/google.cloud.speech_v2.services.speech.SpeechClient#google_cloud_speech_v2_services_speech_SpeechClient_list_recognizers) call?

I'm making the list_recognizers request with:

```
parent = f'projects/{self._project}/locations/{self._location}'
request = speech_v2.ListRecognizersRequest(parent=parent)
print(f'ListRecognizers request is: {request}')
return self._client.list_recognizers(request=request)
```

and my code prints the request as

```
ListRecognizers request is: parent: "projects/XXXXXXXXXXXX/locations/us-central1"
```

where XXXXXXXXXXXX is my GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT Project ID. This ID works for actual recognition calls.  If I give it a bad project ID (XX) I get a proper error message:

```
403 Permission denied on resource project XX
```

so I think I'vm using a valid project ID.

But yet I get an empty iterator back from the list_recognizers call. I don't think that is right, but I don't know what to expect, or why my call might fail.

I've also used global instead of us-central1, and that still doesn't give me any output.

Thanks.

-- Malcolm

Comment: Hi @Malcolm, Have you checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v2#google.cloud.speech.v2.Speech.ListRecognizers) for authorization scopes and required IAM permissions? Could you also share the full code that you are using, if this doesn't help you ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find a permission specifically for ListRecognizers.  I can call many of the other speech-to-text APIs.  In particular my Project ID, a 12 digit decimal number, allows me to recognize speech.

The key call seems to be the list_recognizers call with the request that is included in the example above.

The Cloud Speech-to-Text API product page for my project has a green check mark next to the "API Enabled" text.

I *think* I have seen a page offering fine-grained permissions on the different calls to the API.  But I can't find it now.  Where do I look????

Thanks.